# Решение задачи не проходит тесты

Tags: python, алгоритм

Всем добрый вечер снова. Решая задачу на Python и столкнулся с проблемой. Мое решение не проходит тесты. Я сам плохо понимаю, что от меня требуют, но думаю нужно сделать акцент на это предложение `Известно, что в языке реальных членов экипажа вероятность появления каждого символа зависит от предыдущего`. Лично мне посоветовали сделать частотный словарь всех пар символов. Теперь при вводе символов `3 aba caba aba daba baa cdaa`, выдает число `1`, а должно выводить число `3`

Вот задача:

> Александр работает на таможне в космопорте. Однажды туда прибыл
> космический корабль после экспедиции на Марс. Сканер в порту забил
> тревогу, на корабле находится ровно один марсианин, который
> замаскировался под члена экипажа. К сожалению сканер не способен
> показать, кто конкретно является марсианином.
>
> Тогда Александр решил запросить протокол общения всех членов экипажа.
> **Известно, что в языке реальных членов экипажа вероятность появления**
> **каждого символа зависит от предыдущего. Однако, марсианин этого не**
> **знал и пытался пародировать язык реальных членов экипажа, выбирая**
> **буквы независимо от предыдущих.**
>
> Помогите Александру определить, кто из членов экипажа на самом деле
> является марсианином. Гарантируется, что с имеющимся протоколом
> общения это реально сделать.

**Формат входных данных**

Первая строка содержит натуральное число `N (3 ≤ N ≤ 10)` — число членов экипажа на корабле (включая замаскированного марсианина).

Следующие `N` строк содержат текст высказывания соответствующих членов экипажа.
Каждая строка состоит только из маленьких латинских букв и пробелов. Сумма длин всех строк не превышает `104`.
Формат выходных данных
Выведите одно натуральное число — номер строки, которая соответствует тексту высказывания замаскированного марсианина.

**Формат выходных данных**
Выведите одно натуральное число — номер строки, которая соответствует тексту высказывания замаскированного марсианина.

**Пример 1**

**Входные данные:**

```
3
aba caba 
aba daba
baa cdaa
```

**Выходные данные:**

```
3
```

А вот мой код к задачи с частотный словарь `avg_pair_counts`:

```py
import numpy as np

N = int(input())

# Чтение высказываний экипажа и создание словарей пар символов
statements = []
pair_dicts = []

for _ in range(N):
    statement = input()
    statements.append(statement)

    pair_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(statement) - 1):
        pair = statement[i:i + 2]
        if pair in pair_dict:
            pair_dict[pair] += 1
        else:
            pair_dict[pair] = 1

    pair_dicts.append(pair_dict)

# Создание словаря всех пар символов
avg_pair_counts = {}
for pair_dict in pair_dicts:
    for pair, count in pair_dict.items():
        if pair in avg_pair_counts:
            avg_pair_counts[pair] += count
        else:
            avg_pair_counts[pair] = count

# Вычисление дисперсии для каждого члена экипажа
min_variance = np.inf
min_index = -1

for i, pair_dict in enumerate(pair_dicts):
    variance = 0
    for pair, count in pair_dict.items():
        diff = count - (avg_pair_counts.get(pair, 0) / N)
        variance += diff ** 2

    if variance < min_variance:
        min_variance = variance
        min_index = i

print(min_index + 1)
```

Comment: Вам нужен частотный словарь всех пар символов. У марсианина дисперсия по этому словарю будет самая низкая.

Comment: Как это реализовать? @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Собрать частоты всех пар в массив. Вычислить дисперсию этого массива. Какой шаг вызывает у вас вопросы?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Шаг, который вызывает вопросы, состоит в сборе частот всех пар символов. Он не совсем понятен из приведенной задачи. Если я правильно понимаю, мне нужно посчитать, сколько раз каждая пара символов встречается в тексте высказываний членов экипажа.

Comment: frequency dictionary python example

Comment: Да и вообще есть `collections.Counter`. Преобразовать потом счётчики в частоты не сложно.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не заметил обновления вопроса. Думаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот штука, которая решает пример в вопросе. Из строки извлекаются пары символов. Пары с пробелами исключаются. Для оставшихся пар считаются вхождения в строку. От словаря остаются только значения, которые превращаются в частоты, для которых считается вариация (квадрат дисперсии). Марсианин - тот кто говорит с минимальной вариацией.

```
import collections


def pairs(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    next(it, None)
    return zip(seq, it)


def frequences(seq):
    counts = collections.Counter(seq).values()
    s = sum(counts)
    return (c / s for c in counts)


def variance(seq):
    c = 0
    s1 = 0
    s2 = 0
    for v in seq:
        c += 1
        s1 += v
        s2 += v * v
    # print((s1 * s1 - s2) / c)
    return (s1 * s1 - s2) / c


def variances(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield variance(frequences(p for p in pairs(input()) if ' ' not in p))


print(min((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(variances(int(input())), start=1))[1])
```

**P.S.** Вариации из примера для справки:

> ```
> 1    0.21(3)
> 2    0.21(3)
> 3    0.18
> ```

**P.P.S.** Вариации считаются только для пар которые встретились в речи конкретного человека. Варианты с общим словарём частот/вхождений не работают.

Comment: Пример в вопросе также решается чередованием гласных и согласных. Марсианин не чередует местами.

Comment: нет, ваше решение не подходит мне

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: Ну я решаю олимпиаду и там нужен определенный ответ, который я не могу понять

Comment: Зарегистрировался, до задачи добраться не смог.

Comment: Ну не знаю, что сделать... Извините...

Comment: Соревнование называются "Один из них"

Comment: если это вам что то даст

Comment: Поправил ответ. Я дошел до задачи. Нельзя увидеть полное условие пока некий спонсор не зарегистрирует меня на соревнование.

Comment: Скажи свой адресс, я к тебе приеду и поцелую тебя❤

Comment: Ну впринципе, твой код набрал 50 баллов и прошел 14 тестов из 26, но я попробую сам додумать, как увеличить баллы

Comment: Исключить из расчёта пары символ-пробел, пробел-символ.

Comment: Если тебе не тяжело, то можешь изменить ответ

Comment: Ответ уже изменён.

Comment: нееее) стало еще меньше